# How to make LINQPad work with SQL Server's graph?

Tags: sql-server, graph-databases, linqpad, sql-graph, sql-server-graph

[Graph Table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/graphs/sql-graph-overview?view=sql-server-2017) in SQL Server automatically added an internal graph_ID_ column for user. When querying the table in LINQPad, got this error.

[image]

Here is the SQL being generated in LINQPad. Looks like LINQ_TO_SQL detected this column, and treated this column as normal column, but SQL Server does not allow us to access it.

[image]

I can write LINQ query without this column, it works OK. but since it's a custom query, I lost the ability to edit the record.

[image]

Comment: You share an observation here, it's not a question. What in fact you're saying is, LINQ-to-SQL doesn't support SQL Server's graph table. That shouldn't surprise anyone.

Comment: Thanks @Gert Arnold, I changed the title to make it a question. LINQPad in the past  has a configuration to allow SQL Server XML data type to be generated as string type in C#, I am hoping something like this exists.

Comment: The syntax of querying a graph table is different than that of a standard tabel and never requires the `graph_id` column to be queried directly. LINQ-to-SQL doesn't know this and just generates standard SQL syntax.

Comment: What you're asking is whether LINQPad can ignore graph_id columns when querying, right? I'll try and look into this over the next week, and if it can be done, whether it can go into the next LINQPad update.

Comment: Yes @Joe Albahari, please have LINQPad ignore this column automatically when writing LINQ query, also allowing edit graph record data in paid LINQPad version.